# Initializing excel files in xpress

Tags: excel, initialization, import-from-excel, xpressive

I am trying to import an excel file into the initialization section of an xpress script, rather than hard coding the data.  Could anyone provide an example script where they import multiples columns and rows concurrently?  Let me know if I should provide an example file or more information.  Unfortunately there's not a lot of tutorials/documentation on Xpress online.  Thanks!